# QDateTimeEdit - Hour/Minutes sections resets to empty when focus is lost

Tags: qt, qt4, qdatetime

I have a `QDateTimeField` with mask set as `HH:mm` Consider a scenario where user deletes (for example) hour section like this:

[image]

If user empties the hour section and subsequently press enter, hour section resets to 00 (**which is the expected behavior, always**).

[image]

If user empties the hour section and just click somewhere else (when `QDateTimeField` loses it's focus), hour section remains empty, which is my problem.

[image]

Can anyone hint me with a way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interpretText()` function does the trick. You have to call `interpretText()` of the `QDateTimeEditor` in the `setModelData` function (in your delegate class) before accessing its text.

According to Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html#interpretText)

> This function interprets the text of the spin box. If the value has
>   changed since last interpretation it will emit signals.

Example:

```
void SpinBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                   const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QDateTimeEdit *dateTime = static_cast<QDateTimeEdit*>(editor);
    dateTime->interpretText();
    model->setData(index, dateTime->text(), Qt::EditRole);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a action which connect to the signal timeChanged and manually set the time to the correct format.

Comment: Check my answer for a better way of fixing this issue